# Did Count Dooku know about Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, darth-tyranus

Since Count Dooku worked closely with Darth Sidious to undermine the Republic both internally and externally, he might have known about Order 66. He could have used the Clone Troopers to destroy the Jedi himself. Or he could have turned the troopers against Darth Sidious and ended the destructive conflict to bring order to the galaxy.

**Did Count Dooku ever know about Order 66?**

If so, when did he find out?

If not, did Darth Sidious ever plan to use Order 66 against Count Dooku? (Or maybe Sidious had a separate secret order for the Clone Troopers to take out Dooku and other Separatist leaders.)

Please provide answers from canon sources.

Comment: Dooku knew about the Control Chips in the clone's brains. It's hard to imagine that he and Sidious hadn't discussed why they needed a button that could ensure absolute loyalty

Comment: "He could have used the Clone Troopers to destroy the Jedi himself. Or he could have turned the troopers against Darth Sidious and ended the destructive conflict to bring order to the galaxy." [Order 66 as given in Legends](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Order_66/Legends) would prevent this, as it is reserved for the Supreme Chancellor: "In the event of Jedi officers acting against the interests of the Republic, and after receiving specific orders verified as coming directly from the Supreme Commander (Chancellor), GAR commanders will remove those officers by lethal force..."

Comment: For reference: the Order to remove the Supreme Chancellor is [Order 65](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Order_65) - and requires either a majority of the Galactic Senate or the Republic Security Council to vote for it.  Order 66 is *suspicious* in that it can only be triggered by 1 individual, and only *requires* that 1 individual to trigger it - not even "and at least 1 of his advisors"

Comment: Palpatine was already using the clones to go after Dooku, at least ostensibly. There was no need for any separate "attack Dooku" order,

Answer (score 47):

**Yes.**

In the *The Clone Wars* episode "The Unknown", a clone trooper's control chip malfunctions and prematurely triggers Order 66, leading him to shoot a Jedi. When news reaches Dooku, he realises what's happened and contacts Sidious. From [Wookieepedia's episode summary](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Unknown):

> ... when Trench explains the clone's actions, Dooku becomes alarmed. He then contacts his Sith Master, Darth Sidious, concluding that Tup's behavior might prematurely reveal their true plans for the war, and the two Sith decide to kidnap the clone before the Republic can examine him.

That plot arc also reveals that the Kaminoans know about it, and Dooku was their main contact with the Sith, meaning he likely knew from very early on. Presumably Sidious told him the plan some time after recruiting him but before the clones were complete.

Comment: It revealed that the Kaminoans knew too? Explicitly? That seems a bit dangerous to me

Comment: Yes, the Kaminoans knew, but they were told the Jedi wanted to keep the clone troopers' aggression in check with this inhibitor chip.

Comment: Aren't the Kaminoans the ones who "produce" the clones? I always thought they knew, enver thought otherwise.

Comment: I don't have the episode to hand so I'm mostly going off Wookieepedia but it sounds like [Nala Se](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nala_Se), the investigating Kaminoan scientist, knew about the chips and Order 66 and knew that the Jedi _didn't_ know so she helped cover it up. However, there's a line saying she thought it was a safeguard against renegade Jedi so she likely didn't know that Sidious was always planning to use it.

Comment: It would not make sense for the Kaminoans to *not* know about the chips, considering they controlled the creation and growth of the clones all the way up to delivery to the Republic.

Comment: Wookiepedia is not a canon source. Does the entry on Wookiepedia provide links to canon sources? You can improve your answer with quotes from canon sources.

Comment: @LincolnMan I don't think you can get any more canon without providing the actual scene from the episode.

Comment: There's probably some combination of dialogue I could quote (_"Dooku: Uh-oh, I can't let that pesky Obi-Wan find out about Order 66, our top secret plan to kill all the Jedi!"_) but, as I said, I don't have the episode to hand. [This clip of Trench and Dooku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xPyAUs4id4), with Dooku looking suspicious at the end, is the closest I can find online.

Answer (score 4):

**Most definitely yes**

According to [Order 66](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Order_66) page on Wookieepedia, the official Star Wars wiki, Count Dooku did not only know but he was directly involved in providing Kaminoans with a bio-chip. See direct quote below

> Around ten years prior to the outbreak of the Clone Wars, Jedi Master
>   Sifo-Dyas ordered the clone army for the Galactic Republic. As
>   part of the Sith plot to destroy the Jedi Order, Count Dooku—a Sith
>   Lord who posed as a Jedi to the Kaminoan cloners—provided the
>   Kaminoans with a bio-chip to be implanted into the clones during the
>   early phase of their growth period. This chip contained clone protocol
>   66 which, when activated, would ensure total obedience in the clones
>   and cause them to violently lash out against the Jedi

Comment: The fact that Dooku provided them with the chip does not mean that he knows what was on it.

Comment: "The official Star Wars wiki" is still just a place everyone can edit. Not a canon source. That "direct quote" is still just written by some fan. Never reference wikis. Instead, reference the _references_ used in these wikis.

Comment: Wookiepedia is not a canon source. Does the entry on Wookiepedia provide links to canon sources? You can improve your answer with quotes from canon sources.